# Scikit: Remove feature row if present in all documents

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing text classification. I have around 32K (spam & ham ) files.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.datasets as dataset
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import re
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text 
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold

# Now load files from spam and ham
data = dataset.load_files("/home/voila/Downloads/enron1/")
xData = data.data
yData = data.target
print data.target_names


countVector  = CountVectorizer(decode_error='ignore' , stop_words = 'english')
countmatrix = countVector.fit_transform(xData)
```

`countermatrix` will be matrix with `countermatrix[i][j]` represents count of word `j` in document `i`

Now I want to remove all features where `countermatrix[i][j] > 1` (means word is too common) is present in more than 80% of documents.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
goodwords = ((countmatrix > 1).mean(axis=0) <= 0.8).nonzero()[0]
```

It first computes a Boolean matrix which is True if `countmatrix > 1` and computes the column-wise mean of it. If the mean is less than 0.8 (80%), the corresponding column index is returned by `nonzero()`.

So, `goodwords` will contain all indices of words which are not too frequent. Now you can simply reduce your matrix by

```
countmatrix = countmatrix[:, goodwords]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is countmatrix > 1 performing ?

Comment: @voila: It creates a Boolean matrix of the same shape as `countermatrix` which is `True` where the corresponding entry of `countermatrix` is greater than 1.

Comment: nonzero[0] .. how can you be sure that [0] will be the column-index , it might be the row-index also .. right ??

Comment: @voila: No, the matrix that `nonzero` is applied to is just a row vector.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by setting max_df to something smaller than 1, see the [docs](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L701).

Comment: I think I do not want this .. I want to ignore term that is occuring in 80% of all documents .. Did I understand you correctly ?

Comment: So max_df=.8 does exactly that. Why do you think you don't want that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can retrieval matrix by column:

```
def remove_feature(): 
    remove_index = []
    for index in range(0, len(countermatrix.T)):
        if countermatrix[:, index].max() > 1:
            remove_index.append(index)

    return numpy.delete(countermatrix, remove_index, 1)
```